# Detect navigation history inside/outside website

Tags: javascript

I would like to know where the user come from in each one of my pages in order to provide a back button functionnality like the one by default in browsers.

To do such a thing, right now I'm using `document.referer` , if it's empty, I'm doing a custom redirection with `location.href` and otherwise I just call `history.back`

It works, but there is still a little issue with this process.

If the user comes to the page using a link from outside the website different from a bookmark (like a google research for example). Then I would like to be able to handle this to avoid using `history.back` to avoid falling again on google and doing a custom redirection too in this specific case.

So I was asking if something more tuchy than `document.referer` where existing to detect if the last url was inside or outside the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no in-built functionality that lets you do this, but since you already know the website the user is coming from through `document.referrer`, and you're in your current side you can do:

```
document.referrer.includes(location.origin);
```

And if you need to support IE or Opera:

```
document.referrer.indexOf(`${location.protocol}//${location.host}`) === 0;
```

Keep in mind this code alone won't do what you're asking. This only works for the referrer. You can then make a combination of this method plus browser history to know whether someone's last visit was on your own site or coming from somewhere else

Comment: In fact, I tried to write a simple test.html with a link to a page of the site. The referer seems to be still empty in this case, so it works without others modifications. But may be this is just because the test.html page I used to do this is only a local file.

Comment: If you want to test on a more realistic case you go to any website and run the code above (go to dev tools > console). If you browser through links on the same site it will return "true", but if you come from somewhere else like a Google search it will return "false".

Comment: Keep in mind this code alone won't do what you're asking. This only works for the referrer. You can then make a combination of this method plus browser history to know whether someone's last visit was on your own site or coming from somewhere else

Comment: Indeed with your test method it's not working anymore but your lines give the boolean response I was looking for ! After I just have to handle it the way I want.